# MPI_Waitsome segmentation fault?

Tags: c++, openmpi

I have something like:

```
int numprocs, id, arr[10], winner = -1;
bool stop = false;
MPI_Request reqs[10], winnerNotification;

MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numprocs);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &id);

srand(time(NULL) + id);

if (id == 10) {
    int completed = 0;
    int* completedIndexes;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        MPI_Irecv(&arr[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
    }
    MPI_Waitsome(10, reqs, &completed, completedIndexes, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
    cout << completed << " seems to have completed" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < completed; i++) {
        cout << completedIndexes[i] << " have completed!";
    }
}

while (id < 10 && winner == -1) {
    if (((rand() % 100) + 1) < 5) { // players have 5% chance of completing
        MPI_Send(&id, 1, MPI_INT, 10, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        cout << id << " completed" << endl;
        MPI_Wait(&winnerNotification, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
    }
}

MPI_Finalize();
```

Which is giving segmentation fault, I think its something to do with Waitsome? But what? The error looks like:

```
1 completed
[JM:01317] *** Process received signal ***
[JM:01317] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[JM:01317] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[JM:01317] Failing at address: 0x646574
4 completed
5 completed
[JM:01320] *** Process received signal ***
[JM:01320] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[JM:01320] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[JM:01320] Failing at address: 0x646574
3 completed
[JM:01319] *** Process received signal ***
[JM:01319] Signal: Segmentation fault (11)
[JM:01319] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[JM:01319] Failing at address: 0x646574
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_Waitsome` expects an array of integers where it stores the indices of the completed requests, but what you give to it is an uninitialised `int` pointer. Given the fact that you have hardcoded `10` as the number of requests, the following code should work:

```
if (id == 10) {
    int completed = 0;
    int completedIndexes[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        MPI_Irecv(&arr[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &reqs[i]);
    }
    MPI_Waitsome(10, reqs, &completed, completedIndexes, MPI_STATUSES_IGNORE);
    cout << completed << " seems to have completed" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < completed; i++) {
        cout << completedIndexes[i] << " have completed!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It appears the max completed value is 1? I am guessing its because once the 1st process sends, it will cause the waitsome to return?

Comment: No, it is caused by the way progression (bringing an outstanding non-blocking request to completion) is implemented in Open MPI. You could get requests served in the background if you compile Open MPI with progression thread enabled. But doing so affects the latency of some operations. If you'd like to wait for ALL receives to complete, then use `MPI_WAITALL`.

Comment: Hmm the problem is that not all processes may complete. I only want to capture the processes that finish at the same time (roughly at least)